# vb.net multiple webclient request are slow

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, webclient

I have the following situation.

With Javascript I do 6  AJAX request to vb.NET pages.

```
  $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: "/ajax/ajax.aspx?c=1"});
  $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: "/ajax/ajax.aspx?c=2"});
  $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: "/ajax/ajax.aspx?c=3"});
  $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: "/ajax/ajax.aspx?c=4"});
  $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: "/ajax/ajax.aspx?c=5"});
  $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: "/ajax/ajax.aspx?c=6"});
```

These pages do a webrequest to other servers (websites).
This takes about 1.5 minutes.

When I comment out the webrequest and try them 1 by 1 they are all respond in 20-30 seconds.
So although the request are asynchrome it seems to be that they are waiting for a previous to complete on the server side.

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
webClient.Proxy = Nothing
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString([website])
```

So I Googled around the web and found that webclient has a default connection limit of 2. The answers in these threads tell me to set a higher maxconnection value in web.config. So I did.

web.config:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="1000"/>
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I restarted the website and the application pool in IIS but I still get responses > 1.5 minutes while individualy the are completed in 20 seconds.

So, does anyone know how to fix these slow responses?

Comment: Have you tried looping and creating a new `WebClient` per request?

Comment: Well, there is only 1 webrequest on the .NET page.
The page itself is called 6 times with AJAX. So there is no loop server side.

Comment: Is it worth adding a little write-to-a-text-file when the server method enters and exits, to firstly find out if the requests are being queued?

Comment: Might be, but how do I do that. Webclient doesnt has a "start" function. When I call the function it might queue the request but the request is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was not the webrequest but the large amount of ajax calls by Javascript.
The browser doesnt allow more than a certain amount of connections and queues them up.
So I made 1 request and handled the asynchrone things server side.